# Probability of making a putt

Tags: probability

I want to calculate the probability of making a (golf) putt. The below figure shows a simplified sketch of a putt:

[image]

First, we focus on the angle, *α*.
The dotted line represents the angle within which the ball must be hit so that it falls within the radius of the hole. This threshold angle is

$$ \alpha = \sin^{-1}(\frac{R_{hole}}{x}) $$

I assume that *α* follows a normal distribution centered at 0 with some standard deviation *σ*.
The probability that the ball goes in the hole is

$$ Pr(|\alpha|< sin^{-1}(\frac{R_{hole}}{x}))=2\Phi(\frac{sin^{-1}(\frac{R_{hole}}{x})}{\sigma_{\alpha}})-1$$

Next, we focus on the speed, *v*. The ball should move quick enough to actually tip over on the rim of the hole. In addition, the ball cannot move too fast as it will fly over the whole without being captured.

The probability that the ball is captured is equal to

$$ Pr(v_{min} < v < v_{max}) = \Phi(\frac{v_{max} - v}{\sigma_{v}})-\Phi(\frac{v_{min} - v}{\sigma_{v}})$$

However, v<sub>min</sub> and v<sub>max</sub> depends on where the ball enters the hole.

[image]

The perpendicular line of the two parallel lines represents δ. The further from the center of the hole, the smaller the distance the ball can be captured by the hol. As a result, When

$$ \delta \to R_{hole}: v_{max} \downarrow $$

I assume that *δ* depends on *α* and *v*

$$ \delta = f(\alpha, v) $$

In addition

$$ v_{min} = g(\delta) $$

and

$$ v_{max} = h(\delta) $$

If I substitute all the above I get

$$ Pr(v_{min} < v < v_{max}) = \Phi(\frac{h(f(\alpha, v)) - v}{\sigma_{v}})-\Phi(\frac{g(f(\alpha, v)) - v}{\sigma_{v}})$$

But now we have a new variable in the equation in the form of *α*. So, am I correct to conclude we actually need to solve a conditional probability?

$$ Pr(v_{min} < v < v_{max}|\alpha) $$

and the probability of a successful put becomes

$$ Pr(success) = Pr(v_{min} < v < v_{max}|\alpha) \cdot Pr(|\alpha|< sin^{-1}(\frac{R_{hole}}{x}))$$

Is this correct?

Comment: FYI, the word is "putt".

Comment: thanks, any further comments on the substance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last expression is not meaningful because it has a free variable, namely $a$ in the term $P(v_{min} < v < v_{max} \mid \alpha = a)$.  You are on the right track; the correct formula is:

$$ P(success) = \int P(success \mid \alpha = a) \times p_\alpha(a)\ \  da$$

where

- $ P(success \mid \alpha = a) = $ your complicated expression but using $a$ instead of $\alpha$

  - and $ P(success \mid \alpha = a) =0$ when $|a|>$ the threshold angle,
- and $p_\alpha(a)$ is the pdf (not cdf) of the normal variable.

Note: since your confusion is about probability, I did not check the rest of your calculations e.g. the geometry.